# Prove the following given $0<a<b$.

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, proof-explanation

If $\frac{b}{a} < \frac{a+b}{b}$, then prove the following:

1. $\frac{b}{a} < \frac{a + 2b}{a+b}$
2. $\frac{a+b}{b} < \frac{2a + 3b}{a+2b}$

I have tried to simplify these inequalities, but have gotten no where. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Since
\begin{align}
b^2<a^2+ab
\end{align}
then it follows 
\begin{align}
b^2+ab<a^2+2ab.
\end{align}